# Upgrading TFS 2013 Build Service to TFS 2015 RC

Tags: tfs-2015

I've upgraded our dev environment to TFS 2015 RC from TFS 2013 Update 4. That went really well. Now, I want to address the build environment.

What's the process for upgrading existing build controller/agents to TFS 2015 RC? Ideally I'd like the existing machines to handle both XAML and build.vnext builds.

EDIT: According to the docs, it seems like the existing build infrastructure would not get upgraded. That's fine, I'd just like to be able to manage that agent service through the admin console. Much like you can do on the app tier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS 2015 does not have Build controller concept and supports vnext builds as you have understood.So you need to configure TFS 2013 build controller and TFS 2013 build agents to keep using the Xaml build environment.This will help you address the Xaml build issue.
And you can follow the following msdn article to install and configure new vnext 
builds in your environment:

**Install and configure new build agent and pool:**
http://nkdagility.com/configure-a-build-vnext-agent-on-vso/

**Create build definition:**
http://nkdagility.com/create-a-build-vnext-build-definition-on-vso/
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/feature-overview